# Internal Server Error 500, out of memory error running Yii

Tags: php, yii

So I'm running Yii, which has an application that manages some scientific data.

I'm running Apache on CentOS.

PHP Version 5.2.10
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)

Here's my error log (obfuscated personal identifying information).

```
[Wed Apr 18 15:27:42 2012] [error] [client 000.000.000.000] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \x94512M\x93 - assumed '\x94512M\x93' in /var/www/MySite/www/admin/index.php on line 12, referer: http://MySite.com/admin/index.php?r=factsheet/admin
[Wed Apr 18 15:27:44 2012] [error] [client 000.000.000.000] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57 bytes) in /var/www/MySite/www/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 1856, referer: http://MySite.com/admin/index.php?r=factsheet/admin
```

If I remove the renderPartial() out of my view, I can get the page to load, so it appears it's somehow tied into that.

CActiveRecord.php:

```
protected function instantiate($attributes)
{
    $class=get_class($this);
    $model=new $class(null);
    return $model;
}
```

My Model:

```
Extends an abstract class which extends GxActiveRecord.
```

View:

```
<?php

$this->breadcrumbs = array(
    $model->label(2) => array('index'),
    Yii::t('app', 'Create'),
);
$this->menu = array(
    array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'List') . ' ' . $model->label(2), 'url' => array('index')),
    array('label'=>Yii::t('app', 'Manage') . ' ' . $model->label(2), 'url' => array('admin')),
);
?>
<h1><?php echo Yii::t('app', 'Create') . ' ' . GxHtml::encode($model->label()); ?></h1>
<?php
$this->renderPartial('_form', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'buttons' => 'create'));
?>
```

Line 12 of index.php

```
ini_set(“memory_limit”,”512M“);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You running any painful queries in that partial which apparently makes use of the model object you passed in? Post the query, chances are it's not optimized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message

```
[Wed Apr 18 15:27:42 2012] [error] [client 000.000.000.000] PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant \x94512M\x93 - assumed '\x94512M\x93' in /var/www/MySite/www/admin/index.php on line 12, referer: http://MySite.com/admin/index.php?r=factsheet/admin
```

indicates, that you missed the $-sign before a variable.

Please provide line 12 of index.php. I don't believe the problem is located in the source provided above.

The message

```
[Wed Apr 18 15:27:44 2012] [error] [client 000.000.000.000] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57 bytes) in /var/www/MySite/www/yii/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php on line 1856, referer: http://MySite.com/admin/index.php?r=factsheet/admin
```

frequently indicates a certain looping PHP-operation or complex queries.

You could enhance the amount of PHP memory, but this most likely won't solved the actual problem.

Comment: +1: tried to allocate 57 bytes is an additional array entry often.